# Rollbacks using liquibase Api not being made

Tags: liquibase, rollback

I am trying to do a rollback using Liquibase api but for some reason the rollbacks aren't being made

```
 try {
     Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties("application.properties");
     String dbUrl=properties.getProperty("spring.datasource.url");
     String dbUsername=properties.getProperty("spring.datasource.username");
     String dbPassword=properties.getProperty("spring.datasource.password");
     String changelogPath=properties.getProperty("spring.liquibase.change-log");

     Connection connection = openConnection(dbUrl,dbUsername,dbPassword);
     Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
     Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase(changelogPath, new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
     liquibase.rollback(1,"");
     } catch (SQLException | IOException | LiquibaseException e) {
       logger.error(e.getMessage());
     }
```

This is the message I am getting in the command line

```
INFO: Reading from `saft-demo-dump`.DATABASECHANGELOG
jun. 16, 2021 4:21:10 DA TARDE liquibase.lockservice
INFO: Successfully released change log lock
Do you want to see this operation's report in Liquibase Hub, which improves team collaboration?
If so, enter your email. If not, enter [N] to no longer be prompted, or [S] to skip for now, but ask again next time (default "S"):

jun. 16, 2021 4:21:51 DA TARDE liquibase.lockservice
INFO: Successfully acquired change log lock
Skipping auto-registration
jun. 16, 2021 4:21:51 DA TARDE liquibase.hub
WARNING: Skipping auto-registration
jun. 16, 2021 4:21:52 DA TARDE liquibase.lockservice
INFO: Successfully released change log lock
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: From the console output it seems to be working. Liquibase has acquired DB lock at first and then after processing, has released the DB lock.
Can you try a sample changeset with ```context="abc"``` and in your java code, try using ```liquibase.rollback(1,"abc");```. Just to check if it works with actually providing some value for context.

Comment: tried that but it didn't work